# highest palindrome with 3 digit numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby

I wanted to find the highest palindrome that can be made as a product of three digit numbers in ruby. 
The basic psuedo code would be:

start with 999, go down to 100

multiply each of the numbers

if the reverse of the number is same as the number halt.

here is the ruby code i wrote, does not seem to work, whats wrong

```
start = 100; stop = 999;
stop.downto(start) do |i|
  stop.downto(start) do |j|
    nm = i*j
    nms = nm.to_s
    if nms == nms.reverse
      puts nms
    end
    break
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone for pointing out the flaw. 
Following is what i have come up with and it works:

```
def top_down_palin
  maxi = -999
  arr = []
  start = 100; stop = 999;
  stop.downto(start) do |i|
    i.downto(start) do |j|
      nm = i*j
      nms = nm.to_s
      if nms == nms.reverse
        if nm > maxi
          maxi = nm
        end
      end
    end
  end
  puts maxi
end
```

It seemed obvious to me that going top down would be faster in this case than bottom up(Sergio's approach) hence i did a time profiling:

```
def time
  start = Time.now
  yield
  puts Time.now - start
end
```

On my system the top down approach takes **0.614742 seconds** and the bottom up takes **0.839568 seconds**.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work"

Comment: does not print any value

Comment: hey, but whats wrong with my approach.

Comment: it does not print anything. puts nms. whats wrong with it, is my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14387/discussion-between-user993563-and-sergio-tulentsev)

Comment: It doesn't print anything because you `break` on the first iteration regardless of matching, and `999*999` is not a palindrome. However, @SergioTulentsev is correct - your method also isn't guaranteed to find the largest value. Suppose `999*100` is a palindrome, but `999*x` isn't for all other `x`; and suppose `998*998` is a palindrome. Then `998*998` is larger, but your code will find `999*100`.

Comment: your code has two  flaws: (1) you only break out of the inner loop (try `throw` and `catch`), and (2) you will not find the highest palindrome! See @SergioTulentsev's answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not necessarily find the largest number. You need to find them all and then select the largest. Here's my take. It seems to work :)

```
from = 100
to = 999

highest = (from..to).map do |i|
  (i..to).map do |j|
    i * j
  end.select{|n| n.to_s == n.to_s.reverse}
end.flatten.max

highest # => 906609
```

Also this code avoids duplicate comparisons (`10*100` and `100*10` are redundant).

### Update:

The problem with your code is that `break` only breaks the inner loop. It doesn't break the outer one. You can, for example, make a function out of it and use `return`.

```
def find_highest_palindrome start, stop
  stop.downto(start) do |i|
    stop.downto(start) do |j|
      nm = i*j
      nms = nm.to_s
      if nms == nms.reverse
        puts "i: #{i}, j: #{j}, nms: #{nms}"
        return nms
      end
    end
  end
end

find_highest_palindrome 100, 999 # => "580085"
# >> i: 995, j: 583, nms: 580085
```

This doesn't change the fact that the logic is flawed.

Comment: this way, the number of iterations will be more. going bottom up, better we can come top down.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Can you prove it?

Comment: No, it's not. You need to loop through all numbers anyway. As @Chowlett commented before, your code does not necessarily find the highest palindrome. SergioTulentsev's method does.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please check the updates, top down is faster, proved.

Comment: @user993563: No, it's not a proof yet. Post full self-containing benchmarking code. Also, adapt it to account for anomalies (i.e. run test multiple times, discard outliers and average the result).

Comment: @user993563: Also, we were talking about number of iterations, not the execution time. You measured the wrong thing :)

Comment: if the iterations are more, it will take more time given we are performing same steps in the iteration, right?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev its my second day with ruby, relatively new, could you please elaborate on discard outliers and average the result.

Comment: @user993563: Okay, you are new to ruby. Don't bother yourself with performance right now. Learn the language, learn the standard lib, learn standard tools for benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are nice, but i just had to throw in my one-liner ;)

```
res=0; [*100..999].combination(2).each{|x,y| n=x*y; res=n if n.to_s == n.to_s.reverse and n>res }
```

Comment: using ';' makes it a "one"-liner ;-)

Comment: indeed :) just copy&pasted my irb prompt

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version, but it keeps all the numbers in memory:

```
[*100..999].combination(2).map { |x, y| x * y }.max_by do |n| 
  n.to_s == n.to_s.reverse ? n.to_i : -Float::INFINITY 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what doesn't work? By including break you just end on the first match, so why not add to an array and then print the largest value?

```
start = 100; stop = 999;
arr = []
stop.downto(start) do |i|
  stop.downto(start) do |j|
    nm = i*j
    nms = nm.to_s
    if nms == nms.reverse
      arr << nms
    end
  end
end
puts arr.max
```

Comment: why do i need an array, the first time itself it will print the max value.

Answer (score 0):

Or, in the more ruby way

```
(100..999).to_a.combination(2).map{|a,b| a*b}.select{|x| x.to_s==x.to_s.reverse}.max
```

An optimization would be to move map after select because map returns an array rather than an enumerator

```
(100..999).to_a.combination(2).select{|a,b| (a*b).to_s==(a*b).to_s.reverse}.map{|a,b| a*b}.max
```

Comment: i am unable to understand this complicated code, i won't mind more lines. can you explain how each of them is going.